# Acid-molybdate spray of Hanes & Isherwood

Tags: analytical-chemistry

I am reading a paper where they develop the phosphate spots on a paper chromatogram using what they call " Acid-molybdate spray of Hanes & Isherwood  (1949)".

Any idea what this reagent is?

I tried looking up the original reference but unfortunately I cannot fine a full text version. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15398090?dopt=Abstract&holding=npg

Sigma has "Ammonium molybdate tetrahydrate" reagent available which is described as a component of the "Hanes and Isherwood reagent " but not sure what else is supposed to go in there.

http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/fluka/09880?lang=en&region=IN

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find a re-print of the paper in question– sadly it seems like Nature are mothballing many old papers (dead/missing links).

There are many acidic-cerium/molybdenum type stains that are used nowadays, many of which are commercially available off the shelf, so you might wish to try these before going after something from 50 years ago. (Cf. CAM stain, Hanlessian's stain)

I think this paper may also have pre-dated silica backed TLC plates, which will undoubtedly give you better separation than paper chromatography.

> [image]
>
> Taken from Nature (Nature Publishing Group)